# Parse.com - Cloud Code. How to find object, if I know objectID of related to it objects?

Tags: parse-platform, relationship, parse-cloud-code

Regarding to exist DB structure, I have PARENT object (CLASS1) and it has relations with CHILD objects (CLASS2).

Suddenly appears task make changes in PARENT if changed CHILD. I have ID of CHILD and don't know how get PARENT ID using Cloud Code.

We alredy migrated DB to MongoDB, and I can see here collection: _Join:CLASS2:CLASS1 and can query it to get related PARENT ID. But it doesn't work on Parse.com.

How I chould build my query?

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24578711/how-to-get-parent-object-from-relation-in-parse

Answer (score 1):

Assume you have 2 Classes, named Parent and Child. You have a relation(many to many) on Parent, named children.

If you want to get children of specific Parent 'parent'.

```
var query = parent.relation('children').query();
query.find().then(function(list){

},function(error){

});
```

If you want to get parents of specific Child 'child'(ParseObject, not id string).

```
var query = new Parse.Query('Parent');
query.equalTo('children', child);
query.find().then(function(list){

},function(error){

});
```

Comment: perfectly explained.